# js doesnt work in Chrome but works in IE

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, internet-explorer, google-chrome

I have JS code which works on IE browser. 
But it doesn't work in Chrome and Mozilla.
What should be changed to make it work on these browsers?

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function readFile(url) {
    pageRequest = new XMLHttpRequest()
    pageRequest.open("GET", url, false);
    pageRequest.send(null);

    return pageRequest.responseText;    
}
</script>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    var txt = readFile("?GameID=5&from=0&num=50000");
    document.write(txt);
</script>
</body>

</html>






function readFile(url) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", url, false);
    request.send();

    return request;
}

var request = readFile("http://? GameID=5&from=0&num=50000");

request.onload = function() {
    document.write(request.responseText);
};
```

this code doesnt work neither in IE nor in Chrome))
any other ideas?

Comment: Wlecome to [so]. It appears that you've fallen into the trap of the classic async problem -- see [How to return the response from an AJAX call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call) for more information on this issue.

Comment: probably need a semi-colon....`pageRequest = new XMLHttpRequest();`

Comment: @MonkeyZeus: it has nothing to do with that, though I personally use semicolons where required (without ASI).

Comment: @Qantas94Heavy I don't trust missing semi-colons, ever.

Comment: If your IE is older than 7, you'll have to use ActiveX for your request.

Comment: So how is it possible this code works on IE???

Comment: @A.Wolff man! My bad. I misread the question, thinking that it *didn't* work in IE, but it worked in Chrome and Firefox, as is usually the case.

Comment: @ShengSlogar My previous comment was not for you but for OP which said that his code works on IE which surprises me. And if it's true, i'd like to know why/how is it possible

Comment: @A.Wolff well you still corrected my error, even if you didn't mean to. That explains the lack of the at sign. :) So are you saying his code shouldn't be working at all because of async problems? If so, it might be because IE is *so* slow that it somehow works, or maybe IE runs everything on a single thread. :)

Comment: "So are you saying his code shouldn't be working at all because of async problems?" Ya, that was what i was talking about :)

Comment: @A.Wolff great. Just use the at sign (@shengslogar). I wouldn't have seen your comment except I came to this page by accident thinking it was another question. :)

Comment: @shengslogar oh ya, forget to use it, my bad :(

Comment: I've answered an extremely similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call/16825593#16825593  Let me know if that helps you

Answer (score 1):

This occurs because of  Cross-Origin Resource Sharing, click [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS) for more details. You need to set the Access-Control-Allow-Origin header on server and define the domains that have permissions to access the resource. I tested your code in a server with Internet Explorer and got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You're having async problems. If the HTTP request didn't finish yet, you won't be able to access `request.responseText`. This might work in some browsers because of pure chance. So we have to attach an `onload` event listener.

Try this code:

```
function readFile(url) {
    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET", url, false);
    request.send();

    return request;
}

var request = readFile("http://example.com/displayScore.php?GameID=5&from=0&num=50000");

request.onload = function() {
    document.write(request.responseText);
};
```

You could also pass `readFile` a second parameter that is a function like this instead of returning the whole object:

```
function readFile(url, onload) {
    //load code goes here...

    if (typeof onload == "function") {
        request.onload = function(){
            onload(request),
        };
    }
}

readFile("url", function(e){
    document.write(e.responseText);
});
```

Comment: And gtl.hig.no has to be your own domain, else you'll get 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' errors in chrome.

Comment: @Ruben-J good point, unless the website allows Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS).